# got an exception to decompress a file using SharpCompress

Tags: c#, compression

I am using sharpCompress (http://sharpcompress.codeplex.com/) to compress and decompress a file:

```
public void compressZip(string in, string out)
{
    try
    {
       using (var archive = ZipArchive.Create())
       {
           archive.AddEntry(file2Compressed, new FileInfo(int));

           var fs= new FileStream(file2Saved, FileMode.CreateNew);

           archive.SaveTo(memoryStream, CompressionType.Deflate);
       }

       using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(out))
          using (var reader = ZipReader.Open(stream))
          {
              if(!reader.Entry.IsDirectory)//exception here
                  using (Stream newStream = File.Create("123" + in))
                      reader.WriteEntryTo(newStream);
          }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Ex: " + ex.Message);
     }
 }
```

I got an exception at: 'exception here', reference is not an object... I have no clue why it is like that. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not calling `reader.MoveToNextEntry()`, so the reader is "before" the first entry. You should be using something like:

```
using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(out))
using (var reader = ZipReader.Open(stream))
{
    while (reader.MoveToNextEntry())
    {
        if (!reader.Entry.IsDirectory)
        {
            using (Stream newStream = File.Create("123" + in))
            {
                reader.WriteEntryTo(newStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```